# Создать событие для всех объектов класса в проекте

Tags: c#, wpf, события

есть проект `WPF`, в нём несколько форм с множеством кнопок. Есть какая-то возможность всем кнопкам создать `событие`? В моём случае `MouseEnter`. Мне нужно было, чтобы кнопка меняла цвет при наведении на неё курсором.

Не хотелось бы каждой вручную подписывать событие...

Comment: ну создать один класс кнопки со всеми свойствами и евентами, и добавить на каждую форму. мб

Comment: Да можно было бы так сделать, но кнопки-то уже все созданы в этом вся проблема.

Comment: Можно задать через стили глобально (для тех кнопок кто явно не использует свой стиль)

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комментариям выше. Создайте одну кнопку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630968/wpf-c-sharp-button-style со всеми свойствами и прочим-прочим-прочим и используйте её

Comment: А что должно происходить по этому событию? Есть же стили, есть тригеры, есть EventSetter. Обработчики событий в WPF не используются, за очень редкими исключениями. Уточните вопрос, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: Мне нужно было, чтобы кнопка меняла цвет при наведении на неё курсором.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы менять цвет кнопке, не нужны обработчики, есть стили и триггеры.

[Стандартный шаблон кнопки](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) немного сложноват, поэтому я не стал в него вникать и написал свой. В частности на стандартном шаблоне не так просто поменять цвет кнопки при наведении.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="4">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Button 1"/>
            <Button Content="Button 2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Выглядит это так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь мышь наведена на `Button 2`.

0 строк C# кода, всё работает для любого количества кнопок.

Comment: Воот. То, что надо. Спасибо большое!