# Как переопределить шаблон стиля в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, style, border

Имеется стиль для кнопок:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="DefaultButton">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PressedButtonColor">#3D43B3</SolidColorBrush>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="buttonBorder" CornerRadius="6"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" >
                    <ContentControl Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PressedButtonColor}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Мне нужно создать такой же стиль кнопки, только с CornerRadius = 0. Пробовал наследоваться от DefaultButton и в новом стиле прописывать нужное значение CornerRadius. Не работает.

Comment: Разве `<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="NotDefaultButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButton}">` не работает?

Comment: @Pekor в том то и дело, что работает. Однако, CornerRadius не переопределяется

Comment: ну добавь в вопрос 2 стиль, который унаследован от DefaultButton стиля, посмотрим

Comment: Ну так вы гвоздями прибили `CornerRadius="6"` внутри шаблона, это ведь не часть стиля, который вы можете переопределить затем где либо. У вас должно быть чет по типу `CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding SomeProp}"`, а в самом стиле `<Setter Propert="SomeProp" Value="6"/>`, тогда да, вы можете это значение менять (правда у кнопки нету `CornerRadius`, тут либо свой контрол, либо привяывать к чему-то другому). Сейчас, с таким подходом, в другом стиле вы должны полностью скопировать `<Setter Property="Template">` и в нем уже поменять закругление.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а можно подробнее с этого места: "(правда у кнопки нету CornerRadius, тут либо свой контрол, либо привязывать к чему-то другому)"? Как правильно сделать это: "<Setter Propert="SomeProp" Value="6"/>"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1409441/373567 проще без `DefaultButton` обойтись

Comment: Я так понимаю это про свойства зависимостей - https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/13.php , https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/13.3.php

Comment: @TeraBasedProgrammer Ну смотрите, у `Button` по умолчанию нету свойства `CornerRadius`, да и заменить его особо нечем из того, что предоставляет контрол. По этой причине, вам надо создавать свой контрол, у которого будет это свойство. Самое простое, это сделать новый класс, который унаследуете от `Button` и в нем прописываете `DependencyProperty` (`propdp` в студии и затем нажать TAB), получите нечто [такое](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/fijesusako.csharp). Ну а далее стили, меняете например на [такое](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/icegezohet.xml).