# Как переопределить дефолтный триггер кнопки в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, триггер, style

Пытаюсь навесить на кнопку триггер, который при наведении будет менять её цвет на красный:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="CloseButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF151192"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter  Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Не получается. При наведении на кнопку она становится не того цвета, который нужен (дефолтного, я полагаю). Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: переопределить шаблон (`template`) кнопки

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1409441/373567